# How to read data from other site in PHP and JS without JS tag being shown in HTML?

Tags: php

I have two websites (support.mahtt.host and phonezone.ir), and I want my test.php file in phonezone.ir reads prices from support.mahtt.host.
As per WHMCS documentation, everything works fine but I want it works in another way.
Please check this file: http://phonezone.ir/saeed/test.php
It reads the name from http://phonezone.ir/saeed/name.php and the price from http://phonezone.ir/saeed/price.php, but as you see in its HTML codes, Javascript tag is shown that from which site the price and name are read.

I've started learning PHP recently and I don't know what to search for it exactly over the web. I have tried to work with file_get_contents() and curl() function, but I think I have tried the wrong ones.

name.php contents (php tags are omitted):

```
  $name = "<script language='javascript' src='https://support.mahtt.host/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=name'></script>";
```

price.php contents (php tags are omitted):

```
  $price = "<script language='javascript' src='https://support.mahtt.host/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=9&get=price&billingcycle=monthly'></script>";
```

test.php contents (php tags are omitted):

```
  include ("./name.php");
  include ("./price.php");
  echo "The price of $name is $price.";
```

The current html output is:

```
The price of <script language='javascript' src='https://support.mahtt.host/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=name'></script> is <script language='javascript' src='https://support.mahtt.host/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=9&get=price&billingcycle=monthly'></script>.
```

I want HTML output be like as it's shown in the browser, like this:

```
The price of IRcPanel-A is 81,000 تومان.
```

And when I or any other visitor sees, we only see the above output in both browser and html output.

Could you please help me what should I do to get my expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using php codes instead of JS tags.

I have created another .php file called db.php with the below contents:

```
<?php
  $servername = "MyServerIP";
  $username = "user_name";
  $dbname = "db_name";
  $password = "some_password";

  $saeedIsCool = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($saeedIsCool->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $saeedIsCool->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT monthly FROM tblpricing WHERE id = 1";
  $result = $saeedIsCool->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $id1Product = "". $row["monthly"]." Toman";
    }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $floorid1Product = floor($id1Product). " Toman";

  $saeedIsCool->close();
?>
```

And have modified my test.php contents as below:

```
<?php
  include ("./name.php");
  include ("./db.php");
  echo "The price of {$name} is {$floorid1Product} Toman per month";
?>
```

And now the result is as expected:

**The price of IRcPanel-A is 11200 Toman per month**

Comment: What if you have multiple entries? You should be first of all looking at php with databases along with for / foreach loops, then since the backend code and the front end code will be on seperate servers , you should be looking towards the concept of APIs, for now your current code is not ideal, I would recommend brushing up on php and js

Comment: I'll think about multiple entries. I'm not that much professional  to do that, but I'll find a way for it. Also These two websites are on the same server.